# Vue components not working on live server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, server

My components are not being rendered when I upload my project on a live server. It works fine on my local machine after I run `npm run production` when I upload the changes none of the vue components are being loaded in the page. On my local machine the vuejs dev tools tells me the site is running in production but when I go to the live server in the console it says

> You are running Vue in development mode.

and on the browser taskbar it says

> Vue.js not detected

I have no idea how to fix it. I saw a post saying I should upload the node_modules folder to the live server. But I doubt that would change anything plus it would take too long. **How can I fix this?**

Comment: Can you share the link to the live site? If not, I think more information might be needed. If your local site and remote site are different, it implies that it hasn't been uploaded fully/properly/at all. Are you able to verify that?

Comment: Note that whilst your components are not working, it sounds like Vue is not working at all. Using developer tools in the browser, can you check that the javascript is being pulled in, and is the version you expect?

Comment: @Kurucu Yes the javascript is loaded and I can verify that I've uploaded all the files to the server

Comment: @Kurucu I cannot however give you a link to the site as you need to be logged in to use the page that utilizes vue

Comment: How did you set up your local dev environment?  More common is `npm run build` and uploading the `dist/` directory; I've not seen a build script that uses `npm run production` though I'm sure something uses that...  You should almost certainly *not* be uploading your node_modules folder, but beyond that you'll need to give more info on how you have things set up here

Comment: @DanielBeck It's a laravel project so by default I have to use `npm run production` to compile all the assets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the server was loading an older copy of the js file. So I had to apply cache busting by adding a phantom query to the end of the file. `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js?v=2.4.1"></script>`